# Android post byte array(image) to WCF restful service

Tags: c#, java, android, wcf

I have a WCF service that I am able to post strings to with no problem but now I'm trying to post a byte array as a string and this is where I am getting issues. My goal is to take a picture, convert it to a byte(), send that to the WCF service and the WCF service will insert into my database. I'm not sure if I'm going at this the wrong way though, I can't find any good explainations on saving an image to WCF.

Here is the android code for the httpposting:

```
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(SERVICE_URL + "/SaveAssmt");
        request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        JSONStringer assmt = new JSONStringer()
        .object()
            .key("data")
                .object()
                    .key("sFacID").value(res.get_sFacID())
                    .key("sResID").value(res.get_sResID())                   
                    .key("byteImage").value(new String(imagedata)) //imagedata is my byte() containing the image
                .endObject()
            .endObject();
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(assmt.toString());

        request.setEntity(entity);
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

Here are the WCF pieces:

```
<OperationContract()> _
<WebInvoke(Method:="POST", UriTemplate:="SaveAssmt", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)> _
Sub SaveAssmt(data As AssmtResponses)
```

and then my SaveAssmt method is just an insert into the database which works as long as i don't pass the imagedata. As soon as i pass the imagedata, I get a 400: Bad Request error so I'm not sure if its because the byte size is too large or what the case might be. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode with a standard format, like Base64 (common in web and mobile applications). You can then either a) reconsitute the image as binary on the server side or b) store the encoded string in a database and serve as needed. The answer depends on your particular application needs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried using .key("byteImage").value(Base64.encode(imagedata,Base64.DEFAULT)) but it doesn't save the entire string. It looks like it only saves the first 20 or so characters in the string.

Comment: I have not base64 encoded on Android, but it sounds like it uses a streaming type of mechanism that is only 20 bytes (give or take) in buffer size. If so, find an encoding example that allows you to "stream" the entire image into base64.